# How can I fix this attribute error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web2py

Am working on a web2py HTML view but keep getting an erros.
This is the code:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<h2>Edit your post</h2>
<h3>for category {{=form.record.category.name.title()}}</h3>
{{=form}}
```

and the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

How can i fix the error?

N/B controller:

```
def edit_post():
    id = post.id
    form = SQLFORM(= A("Edit post",_href=URL(request.args=auth.user.id/login))
    return locals()
```

Comment: Your `form.record.category` is returning `None` try to find out why.

Comment: You also have an extra `'`  in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the [SQLFORM documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#SQLFORM) about how you create the form. I assume you've changed the code before you posted it up here, since python wouldn't compile it because of the `=` in the parameter list of `SQLFORM`.